# Criar um header e um footer fixos para todas as páginas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Como criar um *header* com o logo e menu, e um *footer* com algumas informações, e esse *header* e *footer* sejam iguais para todas as páginas? Sem <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, pois se eu mudar algum item, terei que sair alterando página por página. Isso é possível?

Comment: Que framework usas?

Comment: Webforms ou MVC, qual MVC se for? Qual ASP.Net? 5?

Comment: Bom dia, sim é possível.
Se você estiver utilizando webform a forma é a seguinte: [masterpage](http://csharpbrasil.com.br/utilizando-masterpage-em-aplicacoes-asp-net/)
para MVC utilize: [layout shared](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp)

Comment: Há muitas maneiras de fazer isto, mas talvez a mais simples seja usar um _template engine_ como o [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949(v=vs.120).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você cria uma página com *layout* básico que será usado em todas as páginas. Normalmente ele fica nesta posição no projeto: `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. Claro que você pode usar outro locais e nomes e pode até ter vários *layouts*.

Em geral está pagina tem tudo o que está em volta do conteúdo principal e é fixo para todas as páginas. Então tanto o cabeçalho, quanto o rodapé são colocadas nela. Você pode colocar tudo no cabeçalho, incluindo o início do HTML e as dependências básicas. Ele funciona como um *include* de texto.

Mas é possível ter outras formas como `~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml` e `~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml` separadamente. Vai da sua criatividade e necessidade.

É importante que nesta página tenha um `@RenderBody()` em algum lugar que é o local onde será inserido o conteúdo principal da página. Em alguns casos pode usar o `RenderSection()`.

É possível fazer aninhamentos destas páginas. Ou seja, estas páginas podem ter outro *layouts* dentro dentro dela.

Exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>  
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> 
            Cabeçalho aqui           
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> 
            Rodapé aqui           
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando quiser usar este *layout* em alguma página terá que adicionar este código no início da *view* específica:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Titulo da página específica";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Esta página</h1>
<p>Conteúdo</p> <!-- só um exemplo simples -->
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/FixedHeader.cs).

Você pode criar um `_ViewStart.cshtml` que é uma *view* especial que será usada em todas as outras *views*.

Dá para configurar o seu uso no *controller* também, mas isso vai virar tutorial.

Obviamente dá para fazer coisas bem mais sofisticadas, mas o básico é isto.

Espero que ainda não esteja usando ASP.Net clássico. Aí teria que usar [MasterPages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). A ideia é a mesma, mas obviamente a forma de usar é um pouco diferente.

Veja [mais direto da fonte](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).